# How can I get TeXLive 2014 on Debian wheezy (stable)?

Tags: texlive, debian

Debian wheezy's (stable) repositories only have TeX Live 2012 -- what is best practice for getting TeX Live 2014?

Comment: Dowload it from the official page? https://www.tug.org/texlive/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options. Each option have both advantages and drawbacks, so the "best practice"  depend upon your preferences.

1. `apt-get dist-upgrade` to Debian testing.

   - Advantage: Up-to-date TeX Live and OS.  Ideal for people who like to live on the edge but not enough crazy to updgrade to Sid.
   - Disadvantage: You can break something. Not a good idea for a server.
2. [Install a vanilla TeX-Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html).

   - Advantage: Actual TeX Live with a very stable system.
   - Disadvantages:

     - Installation is easy, but no as simple as `apt-get install texlive-full`
     - Many programs as LyX or Gummi have dependencies of texlive packages, so you must install also a vanilla version o these programs or better, deceive tthe system  [making and installing a dummy package](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html) to allow the installation of these progrmas without the TeX Live of Debian (I prefer this because is easy, just follow the instructions of the link).
3. Do nothing.

   - Advantage: TeX Live working out of the box in stable system without effort.
   - Disadvantages:

     - Overwhelming need to upgrade, but surely you do not know why and you will never notice the difference.
     - Finally you will go to a more paifull solution, so ... Why delay the unavoidable?.